# jquery function works inside click but not when called alone

Tags: jquery, function

I'm trying to reach a class element which has been inserted using .html . When I call it in a function through a click event it works, but when I call it straight up it doesn't... any ideas?

```
$("#textarea).html("<div>Lorem ipusum<span class='note-content'>Note text</span>Lorem ipusum</div>");


function collapseNotes() {
$(".note-content").animate({
    width:"50px",
    opacity: ".3",
}); 
}

//this works
$("#button").click(function() {
    collapseNotes();
});

//this doesn't work
collapseNotes();
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the function itself. It might be called too early (before `.note-content` is accessible in the DOM) [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ARmU/)

Comment: it is inside a document ready declaration. How can I ensure that everything is loaded otherwise?

Comment: DOMReady should be enough, assuming it is called after the call to `$('#textarea').html` is made, which inserts the note. As you can tell from the demo link I posted, the function is working when called as in your example. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: ok will keep searching, thanks!

Comment: Or, post more info. Are there runtime errors in your browser console? Do you *know* that your script ever reaches the `collapseNotes()`? You could verify that by placing an `alert` inside the function. You could debug even more by placing `alert($('.note-content').length);` inside `collapseNotes`, which will show you that the function has been called *and* whether any notes were found.

Comment: perfect. did the alert and it does make it. For the sake of the example I simplified the posted code, but here is the actual code, maybe makes a difference.

Comment: $.getJSON('text/1.json', function(data) {
    $("#chapter-text-area").html(data.content);
       });
    

  function collapseNotes() {
   $(".note-content").animate({
    width:"100px",
    paddingTop:"0px",
    paddingBottom:"10px",
    borderTopStyle: "none",
    fontSize: "7px",
    opacity: ".3",
    zIndex: "1"
   },0).addClass('note-content-collapsed');
   $('.note').addClass('collapsed'); 
   
   alert("madeit!");
  }
  
  collapseNotes();

Comment: oops, trying to post code in comment

Comment: `$.getJSON('text/1.json', function(data) {
    $("#chapter-text-area").html(data.content);
       });
    

  function collapseNotes() {
   $(".note-content").animate({
    width:"100px",
    paddingTop:"0px",
    paddingBottom:"10px",
    borderTopStyle: "none",
    fontSize: "7px",
    opacity: ".3",
    zIndex: "1"
   },0).addClass('note-content-collapsed');
   $('.note').addClass('collapsed'); 
   
   alert("madeit!");
  }
  
  collapseNotes();
`

Comment: ok, sorry, here is a fiddle, even though it calls a getJSON which won't work there, but you can see the code.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/reubenlara/RrdNL/)

Comment: That changes everything. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it is evident that you are creating the note in an AJAX callback. Your call to `collapseNotes` is outside of the callback, and hence will not wait until the AJAX request is completed.

Your solution is to move the call to `collapseNotes` inside the AJAX (`getJSON`) callback:

```
$.getJSON('text/1.json', function(data) {
    $("#chapter-text-area").html(data.content);
    collapseNotes(); // place the call here instead!
});

// this is called before the call to $('#chapter-text-area').html, 
// so no notes are found
collapseNotes();
```

Since AJAX requests are asynchronous, the browser will send the request at the `$.getJSON` line, and then move immediately on to the next instruction, which is `collapseNotes()`. It will *not* wait for the server to respond to the request, which is when your callback is fired.

The reason your code worked when executed from a click listener, was that the browser had time to finish the request (hence create the note) before you clicked the button.

Comment: Thank you!! That was it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `collapseNotes();` *before* the content being loaded on the page, remember that JavaScript is an asynchronous language, and you should wait for something to be ready before use it, for example:

```
(function($) {
  console.log('DOM Loaded!');
  collapseNotes();
})($);
```

Comment: According to comments, this is not the case.

Comment: Ok will keep searching for the right spot in the code, thanks!

Comment: can you share more about your code? it seems to work fine here: http://codepen.io/anon/full/LDblp

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    collapseNotes();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your whole JQuery in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//your code here
});
```

that should fix it, by ensuring the whole DOM is loaded

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that it is already inside a document ready declaration.

Comment: This is incorrect. The function will still be called (but the DOM may not be ready).

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/isuqen/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
function collapseNotes() {
    $(".note-content").animate({
        width:"50px",
        opacity: "0.3" // extra comma "," removed
    }, 800);           // animation time !
}

$(function(){ // DOM is ready to be manipulated

    // Missing an " $("#textarea) <--- fixed
    $("#textarea").html("<div>Lorem ipusum<span class='note-content'>Note text</span>Lorem ipusum</div>");

    //this works
    $("#button").click(function() {
        collapseNotes();
    });

    //this works
    collapseNotes();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [**jQuery ready()**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    collapseNotes();
});
```